# How to target a background-image loaded with CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-image, scale

I am trying to target my `background-image` and add a scale to it so it has a zoomed in effect.

But when I load it in using CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url(123.com);
  transform: scale(1.2);
 }
```

It makes my entire website "zoom in". Is there anyway for me to target my specific CSS background image?

Comment: This link might help https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `background-size` for this

```
body {
  background-image: url(123.com);
  background-size: 120% 120%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway I'd possibly be able to do it another way? I just tried it, and it worked! But I'm using cover as my BG-size so that it matches the entire screen, if that makes sense.

Comment: you can use `background-size: 120% auto;` it automatically resize image height proportionally